# Second value of scanf not getting changed

Tags: c

When the `&` is added to `y`, `y` never changes, however if I remove the `&`, `y` changes but the program ends right after the `scanf`:

```
double scan_data(char *a, double *b) {
    char x;
    double y;
    int result;
    printf("input en operator og hvis relevant, operand: ");
    scanf("%c, %lf", &x, &y);
    /* Hvis unær output=0,0. */
    printf("scan y step 1: %lf", &y);
    unary(x, &result);
    if (result == -1) {
        y = 0.0;
    }
    *a = x;
    *b = y;
    printf("scan b: %d", *b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you actually type the inputs with a comma in between? See [mcve].

Comment: I tried that just now but sadly it didn't do anything.

Comment: What do `scanf` [***return***](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value)?

Comment: if i input + 5 for example, the + goes through fine and x becomes +, however y stays 0.0000000

Comment: Also please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], as well as the complete and actual copy-pasted input you give.

Comment: You need to give e.g. `+, 5` as input. The comma in the format string must be matched in the actual input.

Comment: You have other errors as well, the `%d` format specifier is for **`int`** values, not `double`. Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguments to `scanf()` must be addresses for `scanf()` to store the converted values to. If `y` is defined as a `double`, you must pass `&y` (the address of `y`) for a conversion `%lf` which expects a pointer to `double`.

For `printf`, you must pass a `double` value for `%f` (or `%lf` where the `l` is ignored). Passing `&y` is a mistake, just pass `y`.

The final `printf` also has a type mismatch: in `printf("scan b: %d", *b);` `%d` requires an `int` value, but `*b` has type `double`. You should write:

```
printf("scan b: %f\n", *b);
```

Here is the modified code:

```
double scan_data(char *a, double *b) {
    char x;
    double y;
    int result;
    printf("input en operator og hvis relevant, operand: ");
    if (scanf("%c, %lf", &x, &y) != 2) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
        return -1.0;
    }
    /* Hvis unær output=0,0. */
    printf("scan y step 1: %f\n", y);

    unary(x, &result);  // no info on this function?

    if (result == -1) {
        y = 0.0;
    }
    *a = x;
    *b = y;
    printf("scan b: %f\n", *b);
    return 0.0;
}
```

Comment: I removed the & from the printf and it finally worked, however if i remove the l from %lf, the issue persists.

Comment: @LukasJensen: the `l` i required in the `scanf()` format string and optional in the `printf` format string.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("scan y step 1: %lf", &y);
```

invokes *undefined behavior* because data having wrong type is passed to `printf()`: `%lf` expects `double` but `&y` has type `double*`.

It should be

```
printf("scan y step 1: %f", y);
```

You should remove the extra `&`. Also `%f` should be used to print `double` in `printf()`. (`%lf` is not bad in C99 or later)

```
printf("scan b: %d", *b);
```

also invokes *undefined behavior* because `double` is passed to where `int` is expected.

It should be like

```
printf("scan b: %f", *b);
```

or

```
printf("scan b: %d", (int)*b);
```

Comment: Sorry im new to c. Why is the double y the type of double*? Also, if i remove the & the program just ends right after the scan :/

Comment: `y` has type `double`. Using unary `&` operator, you can get pointers to values. Type of pointer to `double` is `double*`, so the type of `&y` is `double*`. Also, you shouldn't remove `&` in arguments of `scanf()` because pointers are required to scan things.